# Get first non-null values in group by (Spark 1.6)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

How can I get the first non-null values from a group by? I tried using [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) with [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) `F.first(F.coalesce("code"))` but I don't get the desired behaviour (I seem to get the first row).

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext("local")

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", None, None),
    ("a", "code1", None),
    ("a", "code2", "name2"),
], ["id", "code", "name"])
```

I tried:

```
(df
  .groupby("id")
  .agg(F.first(F.coalesce("code")),
       F.first(F.coalesce("name")))
  .collect())
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
[Row(id='a', code='code1', name='name2')]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Spark 1.3 - 1.5, this could do the trick:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy(df['id']).agg(F.first(df['code']), F.first(df['name'])).show()

+---+-----------+-----------+
| id|FIRST(code)|FIRST(name)|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|  a|      code1|      name2|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

**Edit**

Apparently, in version 1.6 they have changed the way the `first` aggregate function is processed. Now, the underlying class [`First`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/First.scala) should be constructed with a second argument `ignoreNullsExpr` parameter, which is not yet used by the `first` aggregate function (as can bee seen [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala)). However, in Spark 2.0 it will be able to call `agg(F.first(col, True))` to ignore nulls (as can be checked [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala)).

Therefore, for Spark 1.6 the approach must be different and a little more inefficient, unfornately. One idea is the following:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df.select('id', 'code').filter(df['code'].isNotNull()).groupBy(df['id']).agg(F.first(df['code']))
df2 = df.select('id', 'name').filter(df['name'].isNotNull()).groupBy(df['id']).agg(F.first(df['name']))
result = df1.join(df2, 'id')
result.show()

+---+-------------+-------------+
| id|first(code)()|first(name)()|
+---+-------------+-------------+
|  a|        code1|        name2|
+---+-------------+-------------+
```

Maybe there is a better option. I'll edit the answer if I find one.

Comment: Oddly, I get ("a", null, null) running the line you shared. Running Spark 1.6.

Comment: @capitalistpug, I tried with Spark 1.5. I'll take a look at 1.6 and see why this happens.

Comment: @capitalistpug, I've edited the answer after some research. Please let me know if the new solution is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome research. Unfortunate there doesn't seem to be a better solution.

Comment: There is one important issue here  - `first` without window specification is nondeterministic.

Answer (score 4):

Because I only had one non-null value for every grouping, using min / max in 1.6 worked for my purposes:

```
(df
  .groupby("id")
  .agg(F.min("code"),
       F.min("name"))
  .show())

+---+---------+---------+
| id|min(code)|min(name)|
+---+---------+---------+
|  a|    code1|    name2|
+---+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

The first method accept an argument **ignorenulls**, that can be set to true,

Python:

```
df.groupby("id").agg(first(col("code"), ignorenulls=True).alias("code"))
```

Scala:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(first(col("code"), ignoreNulls = true).alias("code"))
```